# BeforeUnload CORS issue on firefox

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, firefox, cors, xmlhttprequest

Trying to send XHR request in the beforeUnload event.

My test works fine on Chrome in both the global context and in the beforeunload event. The request is also successful on Firefox in the global context. But when I run the same method in the beforeunload event, I get a CORS error.

```
function doSomething() {
    var data = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/test.html");
    xhr.send(data);
}
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", doSomething, false);
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/index.html. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I also tried

```
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { setTimeout(doSomething, 0);}, false);
```

And with this I can see the request being sent by firefox (and I receive the request server side, but I still get the error and don't get a response client side)

I believe I’m sending the right CORS headers, as it works in Chrome and in Firefox (in the global context). I understand it's not a reliable event, since it's relying on some timing before the page is unloaded. But at least if I was able to send something before the page was loaded I would be good with this. But it looks like Firefox isn't even trying :(

I'm at a loss on what's going on here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Even if this didn't get an error, what's the point? When `doSomething()` returns, the page will unload, and the AJAX request will be cancelled.

Comment: This is a test to show the issue, the actual request is a REST call I need to call to attempt to save user state

Comment: Also, testing this on Chrome, I did notice the request didn't complete some times, but did other times. I'm ok with unreliable, I would just like it to work at least SOME times in firefox :)

Comment: It appears you are hitting a race condition with the page already unmounting critical resources before the request is sent properly. Have you tried binding to providing a prompt for the user to save before exiting and re-trigger the beforeunload event on success?

Comment: `beforeunload` is a very tricky event. There are restrictions on what it can do, because you're not allowed to prevent unloading the page completely. It has to be the user's choice when they respond to the prompt.

Comment: @damanptyltd I’m not sure how I would do that :( and thing is, user experience wise, it needs to be seamless. Is this a Firefox bug? I would expect “beforeunload” to execute, you know, “before” it “unloads”